# opendds installation in linux (Ubuntu 20.04) problem during execution of make file

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, data-distribution-service, opendds

I am installing opendds on my laptop in Ubuntu 20.04.
After running ./configure  it is ok.
make command output is below.

```
g++ -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wnon-virtual-dtor -ggdb -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -W -Wpointer-arith -pipe -D_GNU_SOURCE   -I/home/mint/opendds/OpenDDS-3.18.1/ACE_wrappers -D__ACE_INLINE__ -I../.. -I../TAO_IDL/fe -I../TAO_IDL/include -I.. -Iinclude -Ibe_include -Ife -I.. -DTAO_IDL_PREPROCESSOR=\"g++\"  -Wl,-E -L/home/mint/opendds/OpenDDS-3.18.1/ACE_wrappers/lib -L.  -L../../lib   -o tao_idl .obj/driver/drv_args.o .obj/driver/drv_preproc.o .obj/tao_idl.o -lTAO_IDL_BE -lTAO_IDL_FE -lACE -ldl -lrt 
/usr/bin/ld: .obj/driver/drv_args.o: in function `DRV_usage()':
/home/mint/opendds/OpenDDS-3.18.1/ACE_wrappers/TAO/TAO_IDL/driver/drv_args.cpp:125: undefined reference to `idl_global'
```

What should i do to install opendds on my machine?

Comment: I have a few questions. Did you pass any arguments to configure? Did you do anything after running configure besides running make, like running configure again? Can you run `perl tools/scripts/show_build_config.pl` and post the results?

Comment: I did not pass any arguments to configure.